# validating two values in a single text field in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, validation

I am setting a passcode screen for an iOS app. I'm using a single textfield for set passcode and confirm passcode. I'm facing difficulty in setting flags for the two values and validate them.

```
func handleInput(str: String)
{
    if txtField.text?.characters.count == 4
    {
        print("Set Passcode: \(txtField.text!)")

        let myValue:NSString = txtField.text!
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myValue, forKey:"Username1")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        print(" Value1 \(myValue)")

        resignFirstResponder()
        label.text? = "Confirm Passcode"
        txtField.text = ""
```

Comment: We will need some code, reformatting and expected result to help you. Right now I don't really understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: i am trying to create a passcode for ios. after i type 4digits ,i want to save the data and clear the text field . now i am using the same text field to confirm the passcode and again save the new entry.

I want to compare both entries @Kilazur

Comment: You should **NOT** be storing passwords in plain text like this. You should learn about proper password storage techniques, before you start compromising user's data like this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to import `UITextFieldDelegate`, as in the code below. You can do this:

```
class File2: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
var i = 0
var password = ""
var confirmPassword = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.secureTextEntry = true
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newLength = count(textField.text.utf16) + count(string.utf16) - range.length
    if newLength == 4{
        if i == 0{
            password = textField.text!
            textField.text = ""
            textField.placeholder = "Confirm Password"
            i+=1
        }
        else if i == 1{
            confirmPassword = textField.text!
            textField.text = ""
            i = 0
            if confirmPassword == password{
                // save the password... (Your Code)
                // I know userdefaults is not a good way to store passwords, but for tutorial purposes, it's OK.
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setValue(password, forKey: "password")
                print("Account Succesfully Created With Password: \(password)!")
            }
        }
    }
    return newLength <= 4
    return true
}

}
```

### Reading the password:

Check out `UserDefaults` documentation on **Stack Overflow**.

Comment: i am trying to create a passcode for ios. after i type 4digits ,i want to save the data and clear the text field . now i am using the same text field to confirm the passcode and again save the new entry. I want to compare both entries.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know you needed a 4-digit passcode. I am working on it! I'll be back in a couple of minutes.

Comment: i am trying to create a passcode for ios. after i type 4digits ,i want to save the data and clear the text field . now i am using the same text field to confirm the passcode and again save the new entry. I want to compare both entries
i cant use a button to clear the label text and clear text field. 
i can use only single text field

Comment: waiting for your answer.. thanks for the reply

Comment: @VenkateshBammidi   i have updated the answer

Comment: thanku you for sending the code .There is  a error with count property

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event Editing Changed from xib/storyboard

[image: Editing Changed]

end then you can check the text of the sender, so you can use the same function for both `UITextView`s

**EDIT:**

A brief example of the action to check the text:

```
@IBAction func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextView) {
    if sender == passwordTextView {
        // check passwordTextView.text
    } else if sender == passwordConfirmTextView {
        // check passwordConfirmTextView.text
    }
}
```

Comment: I m very new to ios .Please send me the code if any

Comment: @VenkateshBammidi I updated the answer

Comment: I am not using two text fields instead i am using one @SaintThread

Comment: If you must use just a textview you can set the tag of the textview depending on the purpose (password or confirmation). You can use an enum with `case Password = 0, case ConfirmPassword = 1` and then `textfield.tag = .Password` or `textfield.tag = .ConfirmPassword`

Comment: if txtField.text?.characters.count == 4
{
print("Set Passcode: \(txtField.text!)")
let myValue:NSString = txtField.text!
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myValue, forKey:"Username1")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
print(" Value1 \(myValue)")
label.text? = "Confirm Passcode"
 txtField.text = ""
return}
        else
        {
            txtField.text = txtField.text! + str
         txtField2.text = txtField2.text! + str
        }
       
    }